# Produce control voltage from GPIO based on wave file source

Tags: gpio, output

Is it possible to produce Control Voltage from a wave file (.wav) through a GPIO pin?

Would it then be possible to produce multiple streams of control voltages, from a set of wave files through multiple GPIO pins, in parallel?

I'm thinking about this in the context of a modular synthesizer, where the stream of samples (frames) in each wave file would produce voltages in the range from -2.5 V to +2.5 V (5 Vpp).

I'm completely new to GPIO so any pointers to relevant tutorials and software libraries would be greatly appreciated.  I've been googling around but haven't yet stumbled on material relevant to this particular use case.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to play a WAV through a GPIO pin and accurately know the voltage?

Comment: Yes.  Furthermore, I wonder if it is possible to play multiple WAVs in parallel and accurately know the voltage for each of them, at one GPIO pin for each file?